# Is it possible to build my foot brace in Blender?

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to build my foot brace in Blender ?

I am building medical foot braces in a software called Geomagic but when i look at Blender and its sculpting options, I'm thinking, it might better or easier to build something like this in Blender.

The steps I would do are:

1. Smooth original foot scan using sculpt smooth in Blender.
2. Then create a Solidify modifier to create my brace material.
3. Boolean remove the original smooth foot from my offset (Solidify
   modifier )
4. Then draw a curve on the new mesh, defining the outline (cut) of
   my part.
5. Split the mesh (no idea how this works in Blender)
6. Then close the result mesh so its water tight and smooth mesh to
   give the edges a soft corner.

Can anyone help me try this out with Blender ?

[image]

Comment: Looks totally doable. What part exactly are you having difficulties with? Could you edit your quetion to narrow it down to a specific problem you are having, as it stands it is too broad.

Comment: Look into how people make clothing in Blender using Shrinkwrap and Solidify modifiers

Comment: thanks guys. I just wanted to get a feel from the pros if this is doable ?
One little question.. because the production of the foot brace is nearlly always the same... can you in Blender create macros ? so that.. foot comes in.. smoothed.... offset piece by 2mm... then a set cut line.. chop... smooth result and finished....
It would make my life so much easier if I could duplicate the same steps....

Comment: Blender does not support the recording of macros, but such a thing could be scripted using the built-in Python.

Comment: is there a version of grasshopper for blender ? like in rhino ?

Comment: Yes - There is an addon called  Sverchok (inspired by grasshopper) - http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverchok_en.html -- http://nortikin.github.io/sverchok/ -- At GitHub - https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok